# Static files on Django + Apache2 gives URLconf error

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, apache2, django-staticfiles

I am trying to integrate a downlaoded bootstrap theme into my live website

I have a /static directory at the root level of the django project (where manage.py resides) which contains all of my css/javascript files.

From my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = '/var/www/html/aerocredRoot/static'
```

In my index.html

```
{% load static %}
...href="{% static 'assets/web/.......' %}">
```

and my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^%', views.index),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

using Django 1.11.13.

On the network inspector with internet browser i keep getting

```
Using the URLconf defined in Aerocred.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns,in this order:

^$
^admin/
The current URL, static/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css, didn't match any 
of these.
```

I have tried moving the static folder to a subdirectory of my app, messing with STATIC_ROOT and doing collectstatic stuff to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out,

I needed to follow this convention as explained in Django documentation. So I edited my urls.py to match this...

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and then edited settings.py to define

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = '/var/www/html/aerocredRoot/static'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `{% load staticfiles %}`.

Comment: Just attempted, no luck :(

Comment: Have you served a static file before in this project? If so, then your static files config is solid. Maybe the file path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Please insure that format to load is {% load static %} and not (% load static %).

Have you run `python manage.py collectstatic` to store static files in /var/www/html/aerocredRoot/static ?